# passing parameter between pages ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, console, parameter-passing, qr-code

Hi i´m new in ionic and I am trying to pass the scann information form one page to another, the thing its that when I execute the program I have a console.log to check if the info its passed correctly but on chrome console said undefined, letme paste my code:

home.ts where i try to send the info from the scan:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
   private barcodeText:String;
   private barcodeFormat:String;
   private platform:Platform;   
   private navController:NavController;

  constructor(private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner,public navCtrl: NavController,platform:Platform) {
       this.platform = platform;
      this.navController = navCtrl;
  }

  doScan(){
        console.log('scannig product barcode');
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
           this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((result) => {
                if (!result.cancelled) {
                    this.barcodeText = result.text;
                    this.scanningDone(this.barcodeText)

                }
            }, (error) => {
                console.log('error when scanning product barcode');

            });
        });         
  }

  scanningDone(data){
        this.navController.push(TabsPage,{
          data:data
    });
  }
```

main.ts where the info suppose to go:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams , ToastController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';
import { DetailsPage } from '../details/details';
import { Http } from '@angular/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  templateUrl: 'main.html'
})
export class MainPage {
    information: any[];
    item:any;
     private bcData;
        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private http: Http,public params:NavParams) {

            this.bcData = params.get('data');
            console.log(params.get('data'));
            let localData = http.get(this.bcData).map(res => res.json().items);
            localData.subscribe(data => {
            this.information = data;
         })
     }
```

on the console.log(params.get('data')); its where I get the undefinied on the console.

Comment: I just found the problem its with the follfowing line: scanningDone(data){
        this.navController.push(TabsPage,{
          data:data
    });

Comment: I have to change the TabsPage with MainPage, but the thing its if I do that I got the info but I need to open the tabs page which open the manpage, could someone helpme with this?

Comment: Open a new question and describe your problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could have a method in your TabsPage that handles opening and closing pages like this:

```
openPages(Page, Data){
this.navCtrl.push(Page,Data);
}
```

Then in your scanningDone Method:

```
scanningDone(data){
    this.tabsPage.openPages(MainPage,{
      data:data
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using **[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**
look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) as well